# Running Check Check Constraint and still have untrusted foreign keys (not a replication issue)

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key

Anyone any ideas on this one?  As per [Brent Ozar's recommendation](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/foreign-key-trusted/) (thanks Brent and team!), I've ran the query below which shows FK's that are untrusted:

```
SELECT '[' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + '].[' + i.name + ']' AS keyname
from sys.foreign_keys i
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON i.parent_object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE i.is_not_trusted = 1 AND i.is_not_for_replication = 0;
GO

SELECT '[' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + '].[' + i.name + ']' AS keyname
from sys.check_constraints i
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON i.parent_object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE i.is_not_trusted = 1 AND i.is_not_for_replication = 0 AND  i.is_disabled = 0;
GO
```

It displays two keys.  I then run `WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT` against these two foreign keys (they are on massive tables), which takes some time but eventually completes.  I run the checking query above again, and they are still there!

I've done some research online and found that "is_not_for_replication" can be the common cause for this, but when I run:
    `SELECT name, is_not_trusted, is_not_for_replication FROM sys.foreign_keys   WHERE is_not_trusted = 1;` it is showing **is_not_for_replication = 0.**

Anyone any ideas why these foreign keys aren't trusted despite running `CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT`?  It should be noted that I am able to run `CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT` against other foreign keys successfully.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, turns out the Application Code uses `BULK INSERTS` which makes the FK's become un-trusted.  To resolve this, I need to get the Developers to add in `WITH ( CHECK_CONSTRAINTS )` to the `BULK INSERT` to resolve the issue and then re-run the `WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINTS`.  Thanks to Dan Guzman for the prompt.